# Alter the data type of a column in MonetDB

Tags: sql, monetdb

How can I alter the type of a column in an existing table in MonetDB? According to the [documentation](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/TableMgmt) the code should be something like

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ALTER COLUMN <columnname> SET ...
```

but then I am basically lost because I do not know which standard the SQL used by MonetDB follows here and I get a syntax error. If this statement is not possible I would be grateful for a workaround that is not too slow for large (order of 10^9 records) tables.

Note: I ran into this problem while doing some bulk data imports from csv files into a table in my database. One of the columns is of type INT but the values in the file at some point exceed the INT limit of 2^31-1 (yes, the table is big) and so the transaction aborts. After I found out the reason for this failure, I wanted to change it to BIGINT but all versions of SQL code I tried failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not supported. However, there is a workaround:

Example table for this example, say we want to change the type of column `b` from `integer` to `double`.

```
create table a(b integer);
insert into a values(42);
```

1. Create a temporary column `alter table a add column b2 double;`
2. Set data in temporary column to original data `update a set b2=b;`
3. Remove the original column `alter table a drop column b;`
4. Re-create the original column with the new type `alter table a add column b double;`
5. Move data from temporary column to new column `update a set b=b2;`
6. Drop the temporary column `alter table a drop column b2;`
7. Profit

Note that this will change the ordering of columns if there are more than one. However, this is only a cosmetic issue.

Comment: That worked! Just make sure that any constraints on the original column _b_ are removed prior to step 3.